# How to get more results by clicking on a button?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to inquire about the way I can get more results when I click on a "show more" button, without loading the page and without repeating the same results.

For example, I have a result set from the database and suppose it has 10 results. Under them I have a button named "show more". When I click on it I'll see another 10 results, and so on.

Also here is an image:

[image]

My view:

```
@model SmartBookLibrary.ViewModel.UserVm

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-advance table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <i class="fa fa-image"></i> Image
      </th>
      <th class="hidden-xs">
        <i class="fa fa-book"></i> Book Name
      </th>
      <th class="hidden-xs">
        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Views
      </th>
      <th> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ReadLaters)
    {
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img class="img-thumbnail circle" src="~/Images/@item.Book.Book_Image" style="width:75px;height:75px" />
      </td>
      <td class="hidden-xs">
        <h4><b>@item.Book.Book_name</b></h4>
      </td>
      <td>
        700
        <span class="label label-success label-sm"> Views </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-sm grey-salsa btn-outline" href="~/book/@item.Book_Id/@item.Book.UrlSlug"> View </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" class="btn green-sharp btn-outline btn-block sbold uppercase" value="Load More">
```

My controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{                
    //Get current user id to check 
    var x = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var vm = new UserVm();

    //ReadLater Books
    var ReadLaterBooks = db.ReadLaters.Where(p => p.User_Id == x).ToList();
    var ReadLaterBooksResult = ReadLaterBooks.Take(5).ToList();
    if (ReadLaterBooks != null)
    {
        vm.ReadLaters = ReadLaterBooksResult;
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

So, how can I make that work using ajax or whatever? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too broad. What have you done so far? This may help you: http://www.hamidmosalla.com/2015/10/implementing-load-more-button-using-Asp.Net-Mvc-and-jQuery-part-one.html

Comment: Actually that exactly what I want , thanks :)